# How to pass enum value into JPA table that has a foreign key relationship to another table?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, jpql

I have a Java (uses JPA) project that looks like below.
[image]

**On the DB side:**

TableName - Userdetails

- Stores ID, no of items ordered and status.
- The status is taken from another table called status.

**On the Java side:**

- UserRepository is the JPA which has 2 methods to store user data into
  the DB, and to retrieve user data based on the status.
- An enum called Status equivalent to the DB table status.

**Question:**

1. If I want to store the user data into the DB, how should I pass the status field in?

E.g. should I do userRepository.storeToUserDetails("1", "John", Status.CREATED)

2. If I want to retrieve the user data based on status, how do I pass the status field?

E.g. userRepository.findUserDetailsByStatusIn(Status.CREATED)

Answer (score 1):

1.You may add into logic of project `Service` class and use him from main code. in its turn, class `Service` should use interface `Reposytory`

2. Add to Status enum values of code

   ```
   public enum Status {
       CREATED(200), ACTIVE(207), SUSPENDET(400), FINDED(500);

       private long code;

       public long getCode() {
           return code;
       }

       StatusEnum(long code){
           this.code = code;
       }
   }
   ```

---

```
    public class UserService{
    @Autovired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public storeToUserDetails(long id, String name, Status status){
        User user = userRepository.getOne(id);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setStatus(status);
        userRepository.update(user);
    }
}
```

3. Create **class** `StatusCode`

```
@Entity(name = "status")
public class StatusCode {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "status")
private long status;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getStatusCode() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
    this.status = statusCode;
}
}
```

---

4. In entity `User` use setter and getter for `Status`:

---

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private StatusCode statusCode;
 public void setStatus(Status status){
    StatusCode temp = new StatusCode();
    temp.setStatusName(status.name());
    temp.setId(status.getCode());
    this.setStatus(temp);
}
public Status getStatus(){
    if statusCode != null{
        return Satus.valueOf(statusCode.getName())}
    return null;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

methods `getOne()` and `update()` extends from JpaReposytory interfase